# USB Mouse and Keyboard not working in Linux 4 Tegra

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse, arm

I am a new person in Tegra Linux development. I have Tamontem NG Evaluation board with Tegra 3 Chip. I installed L4T sample file system from NVIDIA tegra Resources (https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra) and installed the file system as described in the documentation provided in NVIDIA site. Already these was an SD card with L4T running. i dont want to change the boot loader. So I copied the boot.scr.uimg to root (/) folder and uImage to boot(/boot/) and it starts booting from the existing SD card. After that while booting, some errors occurred in some Bluetooth devices (there is no bluetooth device in the board). So I disabled Bluetooth by giving the following command

```
sudo mv /etc/init/bluetooth.conf /etc/init/bluetooth.conf.noexec
```

Now the problem is that mouse and keyboard are not working. So I cannot log in. Even though I installed desktop, the mouse and keyboard are not working, but the mouse and keyboard are enumerating. The `lsusb` command is showing the USB mouse and keyboard.

The installed file system is Ubuntu 13.04.
Linux Kernel version is 3.1

Comment: Instructed to move from SO, not to be flagged as Duplicate.

Comment: I think the problem is with kernel. The kernel in the uImage and the rootfs are in mismatch. uImage kernel doesn't have USB mouse and keyboard support